# Mysql update column with value if id is in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables, one with products, one with products assocaited to categories, both tables looking like:

```
CREATE TABLE `oclh_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `oclh_product_to_category` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to update oclh_product.mpn from table oclh_product if product_id in oclh_product_to_category is equal to some number, to 26 for example.

I trying sql queries like this:

```
UPDATE `oclh_product` INNER JOIN `oclh_product_to_category`
    ON oclh_product_to_category.category_id = oclh_product.product_id
SET oclh_product.mpn = '99999' WHERE `oclh_product_to_category`.`category_id` = 26;
```

and like this:

```
UPDATE `oclh_product` INNER JOIN `oclh_product_to_category`
    ON oclh_product_to_category.category_id = '26'
SET oclh_product.mpn = '99999';
```

without success. Any tips for this UPDATE statement?

Comment: Why do you not think that those queries work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query should work if you use the right `JOIN` conditions.  TRable aliases make it easier to follow:

```
UPDATE oclh_product p INNER JOIN 
       oclh_product_to_category pc
       ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
    SET p.mpn = '99999'
WHERE pc.category_id = 26;
```

If you are storing a number in `mpn`, why is the type a string?  It is better to use a number type of some sort.

Comment: I don't know why, but my query doesn't works, but your query works. Thanks, Gordon!

Comment: @IvanDimov . . . Look at the `join` conditions.  This uses `product_id` in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I found error, the right query that works is:

```
UPDATE `oclh_product` INNER JOIN `oclh_product_to_category`
    ON oclh_product_to_category.product_id = oclh_product.product_id
SET oclh_product.mpn = '99999' WHERE `oclh_product_to_category`.`category_id` = 26;
```

Thnak you again, Gordon Linoff.